# Загрузка файлов к новости, без id новости

Tags: ajax, php, fileupload, mysql

Всем привет.

Столкнулся с проблемой, которую не очень понимаю как решить нормально.

К примеру, я начал добавлять новость, написал название и т.д... мне нужно к новости добавить файлы, названия которых нужно записать в БД вместе с id новости. Файлы загружаются ajax'ом сразу после выбора и складываются в нужную директорию.

Но как быть, если я передумал и просто закрыл страницу добавления новости. А файлы то в директорию уже загружены и сами не удаляться.

При этом название файла должно содержать ID новости(необходимость).

Что тут можно сделать? При вводе названия новости сразу AJAX'ом сохранять ее?

Comment: Так сначала создаете новость, потом уже к ней прикрепляете файлы.

Comment: это не удобно. я имею в виду если сначала создавать новость, потом редактировать и грузить файлы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть, например, два варианта решения проблемы.

1. Отдельно загружаете файлы с пометкой. Например: `news_id = -1;`
   Когда новость дописана и отправлена, меняете этот `id` на что-то иное и переименовываете файл. 
   Если в течение суток (двух, трех, года...) у файла остается `id==-1`, то просто удаляете его.
2. При создании новости сразу создаете под нее место в БД. Тогда у вас сразу есть `IDшник`, который вы можете куда-то записать, вроде имени файла.
   Если новость не сохранена, она так же удаляется, как и в первом варианте, но уже одновременно с удалением всех ее файлов.

Минусы второго: много больше "пропущенных" `IDшников` из-за недописанных статей.
Плюсы: вы удаляете только те файлы, которые гарантированно принадлежат забракованной новости, то есть не мешаете слоупокам дописывать их опусы спустя много часов.

Comment: Если вариант 2, то нужно дополнительно еще проверять, что та новость которую сейчас добавляют уже сохранена.
Т.е. нужно будет временный ID вернуть и по нему проверять, есть ли для текущей страницы добавления резервированный id. Я правильно понимаю? Потому как без этого с каждым обновлением страницы будет создаваться временный id.

Comment: Именно так. Вспомните или посмотрите Active Record:  
 
Создаем пустую новость. Получаем возвращенный IDшник.  
Показываем юзеру форму написания с этим IDшником в скрытом поле и хэшем, чтобы не перепутались формы, или их не перепутали;)  
Ловим сохранение формы, сравниваем ID, хэш, апдейтим нужный ряд.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!
А зачем в кэш? если скрытый инпут будет, то вроде достаточно. Да и в любом случае по нему можно будет итак определить. или я чего недопонял?

Comment: Не кэш, а хэш. =) md5(например, id+user_id+time), чтобы если юзер что-то изменил, он бы не смог перезатереть уже созданную новость.

Comment: да, описку сделал) я понял про что Вы. Только не понял как это реализовать. Как проверять...

Вспомнил где такое есть. В WordPress. Там при открытии каждой страницы добавления топика создается новый id. Код не смотрел. Но судя по тому, что видел, то просто с каждым новым открытием(обновлением) страницы создается новый id. Это, в принципе, не плохо.

Comment: Это нормально. Если IDшник интовый, то у вас в запасе более 4 миллиардов новостей. Если реально использовать каждую тысячную(остальные закрывать, не дописав), будет 4 миллиона. Это по 100 новостей в день в течение 100 лет. Не переживайте. =)

Comment: id да, int. 
В базе WP такие топики со статусом auto-draft. И эти топики "невидимки", так и висят там. Нужно дополнительно делать запрос, чтобы почистить БД. В принципе добавлять новости будет в 90% случаев один человек.

Думаю сделать проверку на заполненность хоть одного важного поля в форме. Например, если юзер заполнил Название, то тогда писать в БД и выводить нотис о том, что новость сохранена. Тогда не нужно будет чистить базу и не нужно будет id забивать пустыми открытиями страниц. Не думаю что грузить картинки будут раньше ввода названия. Буду пробовать. Путь уже понятен, спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

В одном проекте делали следующим образом - кнопка "добавить файл" клонировала `<input type="file" id="galleryItemPrototype" name="gallery[]" />`(естественно айдишник убираем) в форму, и при сохранении все они были в массиве $_FILES['gallery'].